# 'New Web Application' -> Project facet wst.jsdt.web has not been defined. It is used in plugin org.eclipse.jst.server.core

Tags: google-eclipse-plugin

Re Eclipse Juno Build id: 20120920-0800, OS X 10.7.5

The plugin command 'New Web Application' creates a skeleton with an error indicated in the Package Explorer window.  The error logged error is

> Project facet wst.jsdt.web has not been defined. It is used in plugin org.eclipse.jst.server.core.

^ What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

The plugin was installed yesterday and should be up to date.

The starter project app does appear to run, but I'd like to resolve this before I start building real apps.

FYI this is a completely unmodified installation of Eclipse + plugin with one exception.  I set the project 'Compiler compliance level' to 1.6. The plugin created the project with level 1.4, which yielded many compiler errors.

thanks

Comment: I installed the same software (Eclipse Juno and the plugin) on a linux system (Debian squeeze) and did NOT encounter this problem.